# Pass element index in Numpy vectorization

Tags: arrays, numpy, vectorization

If you have the following code :

```
import numpy as np

def myFunction(element, index):
    print element, index

myVector = np.vectorize(myFunction)
myVector(myArray, currentElementIndex)
```

- How can you pass the `currentElementIndex` value to `myFunction()` in Numpy vectorization ?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :** I'm not really sure of where I should get the index of the current item to which `myFunction()` is applied to. I know how to pass an array element, but not the index.

**EDIT :** Updated with the actual code :

```
import numpy as npy

def getHashValue(character, index):
    return (ord(character) - ord('a')) ** (index + 1)

def getNameHash(name):
    hashValue = getHashValue
    hashValue = npy.vectorize(hashValue)
    hashValue(shortName)
    return
```

Comment: What do you really want to do? Where's the problem? (I don't really understand your question)

Comment: Well I'm not really sure of where I should get the index of the current item to which 'myFunction()' is applied to. I know how to pass an array element, but not the index.

Comment: Can you please show us what you're doing (a minimal working example) and what you'd want to happen? How does your code not give you the item `myFunction` is being applied to? That's exactly what it'll print.

Comment: I updated my question with my code. I want to apply ´getHashValue()´ to every characters in the "shortName" string. The issue here is that this function also need the index / position of each character in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) is a convenience function in numpy that takes a function that works on scalar values ("numbers") and outputs a function that works on numpy arrays (with all its perks, such as broadcasting).

In your case, you don't really need any of that, so a list comprehension using [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is exactly what you're looking for. I guess your code meant to do this:

```
def getHashValue(character, index):
    return (ord(character) - ord('a')) ** (index + 1)

def getNameHash(name):
    return [getHashValue(c, i) for i, c in enumerate(name)]
```